# Is there a relatively easy way to convert a 14VAC wall wart to power a 9VAC guitar pedal?

Tags: voltage, ac

I bought a used guitar pedal that didn't come with the 9VAC adapter but I have a 14VAC adapter that works. I did power up my unit with it and it does work but I'm afraid the higher voltage might damage the unit so I would like to drop the voltage down. I'm not using my pedal at the present time because of this. I'm familiar with voltage dividers for DC. Is there a similar circuit for AC? Thanks

Comment: While you could build an 9/14 autotransformer with relative ease, 9VAC power supplies are available for less than $15.

Comment: Voltage dividers work equally well (and badly) for AC as DC, but that's not a good way to drop voltage for powering your device. The best, easiest, and probably cheapest solution is to get a 9 VAC supply as suggested by @Janka.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your guitar pedal doesn't actually *need* AC. The first thing it likely does is to rectify and smooth the 9 V RMS (12.7 V peak) into roughly 12 V DC using a diode bridge and capacitors. Thus, any 12 V DC power adapter should work (albeit cheap switching mode ones might inject noise into the audio path).

Comment: @jms I wouldn't be surprised if it was dual half wave rectified to get +/- 12 V.

Comment: Does the guitar pedal happen to also work from a 9 V battery? Could you perhaps tell us the make and model?

Answer (score 2):

The problem to be solved is one of peak voltage - your pedal may not survive for long with the 20 volt peak produced by 14 V RMS so, reducing the peak to more like 12.7 volts is the general idea.

Parallel back-to-back diodes like this will "lose" you about 0.6 volts: -

[image]

So if you step and repeat using 12 pairs of diodes you reduce the peak voltage from about 20 volts to about 12.8 volts and this is about the same peak voltage as you would get from a 9 V RMS sine wave.

Alternatively, use series back-to-back zener diodes to lose the excess voltage. This is one option: -

[image]

But you need to know how much resistance you need to add and this means taking measurements of current. Another version would place the series zeners in line with the feed to your pedal.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who responded. I like @Andy aka's answer. I have a LOT of 4148 diodes. I know most pedals use 9vdc, and I do have several extra adapters, but this Line 6 Pod Ext calls for 9vac. Behringer V-amp2 pedals use  ac adapter with 11vac and 20vac outputs and their Xenyx 802 mixer uses 17vac. I was trying to avoid having to buy adapter for the Pod and I'm very squeamish about opening up something like this unless I really have to. Just out of curiosity, could I use one diode on each leg instead of parallel on one leg, per your diagram?

Comment: I just wanted to add one observation. Most of my dc adapters, say 9v, show on my meter as 12 or more volts, no load. But my 14vac adapter shows 14vac. Is this due to inherent differences between ac and dc, or could the ac adapter not be putting out full voltage?

Comment: On my curiosity question, I just realized putting a diode on each leg would rectify it to dc, right? Please forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

Most guitar pedals seem to operate at 9V DC and draw very little current. You can check how much current your guitar pedal draws. If it is very little (<50mA), then one can simply open up the guitar pedal and replace the smoothing capacitor with a higher voltage one.

Capacitor voltage rating = open voltage of the AC adapter * 1.414 * 1.2
and capacitance probably 470uF or more

Alternately, a 12V DC adapter should also be fine, but I would check inside first to see that there is in fact a diode bridge and voltage regulator and that the actual circuit works on 9V DC and not 12V DC or AC. (open up guitar pedal and measure voltage after diode bridge and/or voltage regulator if any).

If indeed you want to clip the AC peaks of the 14V transformer output, a pair of LM317 is possibly easier to get hold of than high wattage zeners. LM317 datasheet has a circuit, but one will need to run a spice simulation to find the resistor values for the RMS and peak voltages.